# Filtering a listview based on options

Tags: android, listview, filtering

I have a `ListView` connected to a custom `ArrayAdapter`. The adapter takes objects that have  3 strings - (name, telephone, P.O BOX). I am trying to implement a filtering system for my `ListView` which can filter the list by a **name which they can select from a spinner**. Afte r they select a particular name, the list should show objects with only that name.

I searched a lot for a solution but couldn't find any good examples to solve my problem since this is implemented in many applications, I am sure there an easy solution. Thanks a lot.

Comment: you will have to update the adapter everytime, whenever the search query changes, create a new adapter and apply it to your listView.

Comment: can you show us what you have tried, a code snippet would be better.